# Delete with cascade in spring with JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm developing a delivery system for supermarket products.
I have Orders which contain a list of items. Each item contains a product.
I'm trying to delete a product, I'm performing a logic deletion by setting a flag in my product entity. But I have to remove the item which belongs to a product and also recalculate the price of the order and update its items.

Here's my code

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "order", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Item> items;

    private float totalPrice;
}
```

Item.java

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn( name="id_order" )
    private Order order;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn( name="id_product" )
    private Product product;

    private boolean active;

}
```

**ProductController.java**

```
@DeleteMapping("/remover-producto/{product_id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void removerProducto(@PathVariable long product_id) {
    Optional<Product> productToRemove = productService.findProduct(product_id);
    // Get the product to remove
    if(productToRemove.isPresent()) {
        // Perform logical deletion
        productToRemove.get().setActive(false);
        // Update entity with flag
        productService.eliminarLogico(productToRemove.get());
        // get item from the product_id
        Optional<Item> itemToRemove = itemService.itemWithProductId(product_id);
        if(itemToRemove.isPresent()) {
            // physical removal of item
            orderService.removeItemFromOrderAndUpdatePrice(itemToRemove.get());
        }
    }
}
```

**OrderServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
    public void removeItemFromOrderAndUpdatePrice(Item item) {
        // get order that contains the item
        Optional<Order> orderToUpdate = orderRepository.findOrderWithItemId(item.getId());

        if(orderToUpdate.isPresent()) {
            // update total price from order
            float total = orderToUpdate.get().getTotalPrice() - item.getProduct().getPrice();
            orderToUpdate.get().setTotalPrice(total);
            // filter to remove item from order items
            List<Item> updatedItems = orderToUpdate.get().getItems()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(oldItem -> oldItem.getId() != item.getId())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
           
            orderToUpdate.get().getItems().clear();
            orderToUpdate.get().setItems(updatedItems);
            // It is not updating with the new list of items.
            orderRepository.save(orderToUpdate.get());
        }
    }
```

I defined the list of items in **order** with cascade type persist and remove. But the item is still in the database. The product is successfully deleted (logically) and the order has the correct total price.

I tried adding **orphanRemoval=true** but I get --> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.bd.tpfinal.model.Order.items

Answer (score 1):

isn't your mapping incorrect? I guess it should be a ManyToOne relationship

```
@Entity
public class Item {
  
  ...

  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn( name="id_order" )
  private Order order;

  ...
```

}

Comment: yes, you are right thanks, but the item is not being removed from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This method does the exact opposite of what u want to do.It returns a list with the item you want to remove and does not remove the item

```
  // filter to remove item from order items
        List<Item> updatedItems = orderToUpdate.get().getItems()
                .stream()
                .filter(oldItem -> oldItem.getId() == item.getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in order to remove item from the list you have to filter and select all items whose id is not equal to item id.